# How does Git diff work in the Visual Studio Code Git extension?

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a version control extension in Visual Studio Code. I tried to look at the Git implementation in Visual Studio Code. The confusing part is file diff. In the Git extension source code, for seeing the file changes, `vscode.diff` is used. To get the [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) of the original file, The new URI is generated by changing the `scheme` of the modified file's URI. How is this working?

For example, in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/src/commands.ts, `getRightResource` method, `toGitUri` is called with the URI of the file. `toGitUri` implemention is as follows,

```ts
export function toGitUri(uri: Uri, ref: string, replaceFileExtension = false): Uri {
    return uri.with({
        scheme: 'git',
        path: replaceFileExtension ? `${uri.path}.git` : uri.path,
        query: JSON.stringify({
            path: uri.fsPath,
            ref
        })
    });
}
```

Here, `toGitUri` is just changing the scheme of the file from `file` to `git` with the query. This URI is then provided to *vscode.diff* along with the original URI of the file to show the Git diff. How is the `toGitUri` working here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the diff does not happen here. I also think you have correctly understood what this function does: it takes a file URI for file on disk and finds the corresponding URI for the Git repository. And then it has the two resources to compare.

Those two resources are then passed to the built-in diffing functionality.

Let's track the code in 1.12.1 (follow the links one by one):

- `vscode.diff` is registered [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.12.1/src/vs/workbench/api/node/extHostApiCommands.ts#L207)
- It [delegates](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.12.1/src/vs/workbench/api/node/extHostApiCommands.ts#L217) to `_workbench.diff`
- That one is registered [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.12.1/src/vs/workbench/electron-browser/commands.ts#L377) and [delegates](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.12.1/src/vs/workbench/electron-browser/commands.ts#L392) to editor's built-in diff ...
- ... like this: `editorService.openEditor({ leftResource, rightResource, ...)` ...
- ... where `leftResource` is file on disk and `rightResource` is URI for file in the Git repository.

Comment: For those interested, I've extracted vscode's internal diffing algorithm in to a separate npm package called [vscode-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-diff). In the source you can see a reference path to the original file in [vsode's repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode).